# Columns are truncating in Azure data factory

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I am reading tab separation file from PuBchem data source(data urlhttps://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubchem/Compound/Extras/MeSH-Pharm) from here, I am using azure data factory to get the data from the Url location and to blob storage. But the data factory is giving only 3 columns this is how my data set looks like
[image]

data preview [image]

Comment: When you open the file from blob does it have the full fields there or is it also truncated there?

Comment: when I download the file and open I can see all 8 columns. But when I open from Azure Data Factory I can only see 3 columns

Comment: That's just a preview right ?

Comment: yes that is just the preview

Answer (score 2):

`Data preview` show limited number of rows when previewed. The number of columns shown in preview is adopted from the first row in the file.

**Just make sure the data loaded into storage is not truncated**.

In my example file, I have data with more than 3 columns, but my first row has only 3 columns, so in preview data the number of columns show as 3. But file loaded to my storage with all columns as expected.

(Here my row 10 have 4 columns but shown as 3 in data preview).
[image]

When I edited the file to move the row with 4 columns to the top and preview, it shows 4 columns.

[image]